# JSon and Ambiguos use of subscript

Tags: ios, json

i'm developing iOS application
and with latest updates i go t this error : ambiguous use of subscript

for this code :

```
let json: AnyObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
return (json[0]) as! NSDictionary
```

Is there any solution?
Thank you.

Comment: You may have to explicitly say that `json` is a Array.

Comment: Try to write like this `return (json as! NSArray)[0] as! NSDictionary` or batter if you use swift array  `return (json as! [[String:AnyObject]])[0] as! [String:AnyObject]`

Answer (score 1):

Since you annotate `json` as `AnyObject` the compiler is not able to infer the type if it's a `Dictionary` (key subscription) or an `Array`(index subscription). That's the ambiguity.

The solution is to cast the object to the proper type

```
let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! [[String:AnyObject]]
return json[0]
```

PS: Use always Swift native collection types. The Foundation `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` don't contain type information and the option `.MutableContainers` is not needed in most of the cases.

Comment: Thank you. Swift for me is still hard to understand sometimes.